# Is there Machine Translation Service in Office365?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, client-object-model, machine-translation

Does SharePoint with Office 365 have Machine Translation Service? Can it be turned on?

I created small app, based on [MSDN code sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/SharePoint-2013-Perform-a-8e53b06a), and I'm trying to create translate job for document in my library. Unfortunatelly, I get `ServerException`:

> The service application required to complete this request is unavailable.

This suggests, that there is no translation service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This services is not available in the SharePoint Online. currently they are offering this on-prem only.

For complete list of features available on O365 please check this.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e1ee081-cab8-4c1b-9783-21c38ddcb8b0#bkmk_tableo365

Answer (score 0):

Currently they are offering the Machine translation services with activating SharePoint translation services https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e1ee081-cab8-4c1b-9783-21c38ddcb8b0#bkmk_tableo365

In all the Enterprise options.